# Read Flash Memory using PEmicro and CodeWarrior IDE (MC9S12XET256 MCU)

Tags: c, embedded, codewarrior

I am attempting to read the flash memory of the `MC9S12XET256` MCU for inspection and exploration purposes, using the following tools:

1. CodeWarrior IDE
2. PEmicro Debugger

Unfortunately, I have been unable to locate an option within CodeWarrior that allows me to read the flash without loading into it. Currently, there is only one option (Debug F5) that erases the flash, loads the newly compiled code, and then enters debugging mode.

I also discovered a tool on the official PEmicro website under the PKG Software Packages group, but it comes with a price tag of around $400.

Is there any method or workaround to read the flash memory without altering its contents using the mentioned setup?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If the device is secured, you _can't_ read it - you will have to erase it and download the program anew. Otherwise the old PE Micro tools should have this possibility iirc. I haven't used these in quite a while.

Comment: Thanks, in my case the device is not secured, "the old PE Micro tools" can you name one?

Comment: I don't even remember what they were called, the ones in your screen shot. PROG12 or something maybe?

Comment: Though I'm not sure at what extent they supported S12X. I mostly worked with S12.

Comment: Most debuggers have a "connect without loading" option - possibly that "Change MCU/Connection..." menu in teh screen shot - but just guessing, not familiar with your toolchain.   Or you could just connect to it and read the flash using the stand-alone programming tool:  https://www.pemicro.com/products/product_viewDetails.cfm?product_id=15320181 (I assume you are using a PEMicro probe?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with your toolchain, but I would expect an ability to disable loading an executable on debugger start-up.  Looking for such a capability on PEMicro suggests this (in red - the image is from a blog on a different issue on PEMicro site):

[image]

[image]

No doubt better information in the [user manual](https://www.pemicro.com/support/download_processor.cfm), but requires an account to download, which I have no need for.

Comment: The "Hiwave" debugger that came with the classic Codewarrior was a bit weird in this regard since if you launched it from the IDE, there were a bunch of scripts dictating what it would do, by default essentially switching between full simulator, RAM build or flash. I think you would have to launch that debugger as a stand-alone executable outside Codewarrior, load an .elf file so that it had a clue what to do, but find some option to disable overriding the present executable.

Comment: Although some flavours of Codewarrior didn't use Hiwave but the PE debugger (which was much worse). I'm not sure which one that applies in case of S12X.

Comment: @Lundin. Agreed, if the "integration" does not give full control, run the debugger separately. The information above was purely related to PE, and not Codewarrior at all.